# Two identically-named functions with different parameters, one without a scope resolution operator, the other with

Tags: java

I'm in the process of converting a program from C++ to Java. In my C++ code, I have two functions within class SomeClass that have the same name, but with different parameters, and with one function using a scope resolution operator and the other without.

```
SomeOtherType* SomeClass::foo()
{
//some code
}
```

and

```
SomeOtherType* foo(list<Token*>& param)
{
//some more code
}
```

Since Java doesn't use scope resolution operators, how do I implement these functions equivalently in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even in C++, the scope resolution operator should not affect the overloading behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloading basically works the same in Java. You can define multiple methods with the same name as long as their parameters differ. So you can just write:

```
public SomeOtherType foo() {
  return null;
}

public SomeOtherType foo(List<Token> tokens) {
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since they have different parameters you can still create the method of the same name. They will be simply overloaded methods.